# How to setup subdomain DNS in Windows Server 2016

Tags: vps, subdomain, windows-server-2016, dns-hosting

I have purchased a Windows VPS from godaddy with Self Managed option. I want to use it for website hosting purpose. I thought it would be easier to setup the IIS and DNS etc, but now its looking tough as programming job. :)

Somehow, I have managed to setup the IIS and DNS and made the main website live.

Now I want to add subdomain so I have added Host(A) record, but ping shows the 'host could not found "dev.example.com". DNS details are here.

[image]

I am not sure further what I need to do. I had purchased the domain from a different vendor. My apologies, I think just missing some basic concepts. Thanks

Comment: run `nslookup dev.mydomain.com` and see if it actually resolves to the IP you're using. Generally dns takes a little bit of time to update if this server is authoritative for your domain. Typically there is little reason to host dns on the server as it just adds to extra complexity, but if it's already working more power to you.

Comment: Sorry,it shows the message Server:UnKnown.The main domain is working with same IP.

Comment: Did you have to open firewall ports to the server to allow DNS traffic to be served by your server or just http/https? I'm thinking that you're not actually serving DNS from this server but from where the domain is registered. If you do this command `nslookup -type=ns mydomain.com` it will show you who the authoritative nameservers are.

Comment: I have just open few ports like 80 and Database related. I am not able to get ns info by this command. its look like some domain issue. https://www.cartright.pk/

Comment: lets try from a public server like google `nslookup -type=ns mydomain.com 8.8.8.8`

Comment: `Sorry,it shows the message Server:UnKnown` - You can ignore that. That message is because you don't have a reverse lookup zone. It has no bearing on your problem. What DNS server are you querying when you try to resolve the sub-domain? Are you querying the server where the DNS zone is hosted?

Comment: Now its shows: Non-authoritative answer:
cartright.pk    nameserver = ns16.domaincontrol.com
cartright.pk    nameserver = ns15.domaincontrol.com

Comment: @joeqwerty I am querying from my VPS.

Comment: Add an 'A' entry into your ISP's DNS, not your own private one.